# Spring Security Junit Token Authentication Test - Bad Credentials

Tags: spring, junit, spring-security

I have a spring security setup with HeaderHttpSessionStrategy & custom UserDetailService. It works fine, and login works as expected when testing in POSTMAN. However, it returns BadCredentials error when tested with JUnit. Can you help me solve this issue, because i need to test my application with a authenticated user.

Following is my Method:

```
@Test
public void testLogin() throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> credentials = new HashMap<>();
    credentials.put("username", testUsername);
    credentials.put("password", testPassword);
    mockMvc.perform(post("/login").content(mapper.writeValueAsBytes(credentials))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.authToken").isNotEmpty());
}
```

Comment: If you are using the default login /POST endpoint of spring security then the username & password must be as a Form param in request body & not as json (mapper.writeValueAsBytes(credentials)).

Comment: Just look at the official documentation : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html#testing-form-based-authentication

Comment: @Pratik Shah. You guided me to the right place. Its works. Thanks.